# Scipy filter : force minimal value of SOS coefficient to prepare integer filter

Tags: python, filter, scipy, integer, butterworth

I try to design a low-pass filter (cutting around 40Hz) with Scipy, which seems to work with the following code:

```py
fs = 100000 # Sampling frequency = 100kHz

N, Wn = signal.buttord(40/(fs/2), 50/(fs/2), 0.1, 5)
sos = signal.butter(N, Wn, 'low', output='sos')
```

This filter must eventually be embedded on a board without FPU so I must convert the SOS into an array of integers.

But here is the issue: *some coefficients of the first line of the SOS matrix are too low to be converted into 32 bits integers*:

```
[ 8.00108536e-32  1.60021707e-31  8.00108536e-32  1.00000000e+00
  -9.97022785e-01  0.00000000e+00]
```

Replacing the almost null value by 0 or 1 (once all other coefficients scaled up) did not work.

Do you know a scipy utility that forces the design of a filter to be compatible with a conversion to integer ?

If not, do you know how can I change the `buttord` or `butter` args to increase the coefficients of the first line ? (the sampling freq and the cut frequency cannot be changed).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it with a post-treatment.
Back to the definition of the SOS, the three first columns are the coefficients of the numerator of cascaded [biquad filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_biquad_filter).

Therefore the negative powers of the coefficient of the first line can be spread over all the lines.
For instance as follow:

```py
power = int(np.log10(np.abs(sos[0, 0:3]).mean())-1)
power_by_line = -power // len(sos)
scale = 10 ** (-power_by_line)

for i in range(1, len(sos)):
    sos[i, 0:3] = sos[i, 0:3] * scale

remaining = (len(sos)-1)*power_by_line
sos[0, 0:3] = sos[0, 0:3] * 10**remaining
```

The resulting filter seems to have the same behavior (for the numerical precision that I require).